# How to make a Spring Boot WAR work on JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, war, spring-boot

I tried to deploy a Spring Boot application packaged as a WAR on JBoss AS 7.1.1 (Windows 7 Enterprise) and it failed with an error. In order to weed out issues with my own application, I decided to try again with a simpler app by following the Spring guide [Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/).

I downloaded the [source for the guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war/archive/master.zip) and compiled the "completed" version as instructed to create a WAR, but the package fails with the same error on deployment.

```
11:59:37,490 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter errorPageFilter: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer can not access a member of class org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:349) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:80) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

I looked at the source for [`ErrorPageFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0d44e6e0d222d77b057390c6b6411594f7779381/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/ErrorPageFilter.java) and noticed that the class is package private, which is probably the cause of the `IllegalAccessException`.

So my question…

- Is the class being package private actually the cause?
- If so, is there any way I can work around the issue (e.g. Java magic) without giving up `ErrorPageFilter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [in github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/933) I believe that is the cause of the error you see (which we agreed is a bug in JBoss).

If you want a workaround, just copy the `SpringBootServletInitializer` code, make your own class wit the same content, but take out the bits that hurt.

Unfortunately I don't think just making the `ErrorPageFilter` publicly accessible will fix your app in JBoss, and indeed you have indicated that is the case.